# How to add items to an array in Redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm building an Electron application and I'm trying to keep an array of images that are on each page so if the page is deleted I can easily delete all the associated images from the filesystem.

**What I have now:**

```
const initialState = [{
  uuid: '65ec81f5-a783-4abd-bd0d-1451adda58c6',
  imageUUIDs: []
}];

const actionsMap = {
   [ActionTypes.ADD_IMAGE_TO_PAGE](state, action) {
        const pageUUID = action.pageUUID;
        const imgUUID = action.imgUUID;
        return state.map(page =>
          (page.uuid === pageUUID ?
            Object.assign({}, page, {
              imageUUIDs: page.imageUUIDs.splice(0, 0, imgUUID),
            }) : page)
        );
  },

};
```

This initially seems to work when viewed at runtime, but I end up with an empty array after completion. What is the right way to maintain a list like this?

Comment: Do you want add element to `imageUUIDs` array right? Have you tried with `push` method?

Comment: If you are trying to add items to the array you probably want to use `Array.prototype.concat` instead of `Array.prototype.splice`. `concat` will return a new array whereas `splice` modifies the original array. Meaning, `page.imageUUIDs.splice(0, 0, imgUUID)` is modifying the original array, but not returning the array, which is what you are expecting. If you use `Array.prototype.push` you are again modifying the original array. Meaning you would need to create a reference to that new array and pass it in to `Object.assign`.

Comment: Adam this is the answer. Thanks very much! If you provide this as an answer rather than a comment I'll mark it the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.concat` instead of `Array.prototype.splice`. `Array.prototype.concat` returns a new array whereas `Array.prototype.splice` modifies the original array but does not return a new array, which is not what you are expecting.